# Print to paper selected data

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database (image1) and using PHPMaker i created the graphic interface (image2). What i want is to add a button at the bottom of the page that will print the selected data from the selected fields (image3).

Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Do i have to use php code or a javascript?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a print link by echoing the following to create a "Print" link on the page

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:window.print();'>Print Page</a>";
```

Button click will make the browser present the user with the default print dialog.